# Storing a token acquired through a fetch in Local Storage and appending data from a fetch request in a html table

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project with a couple of people using C#, HTML and Javascript.

We have to make the classic game Mastermind and make it multiplayer, I'm struggling with some things on the front end side. The backend is being done by the other people and it is pretty much finished.

We have to use fetch to make requests to our backend. I already made a system that allows for logging in and registering. We have to use a token for authentication and I can't seem to figure out how to get the token from the response from my fetch request and store in Local Storage. Another thing I'm struggling with is the lobbies for the game. I have to use fetch to ask my backend for the currently running lobbies, to create lobbies, and joining and leaving lobbies. As for the currently running lobbies, I have to convert the response I'm getting from my backend to a table on my HTML page but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

I have tried searching for possible solutions using Google but I don't really understand what the solutions do and how to mold them to work for my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getRooms();
    return false;
});

function getRooms() {
    let url = 'https://localhost:44317/api/waitingrooms';


    let table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.setAttribute("id", "waitingRooms");
    let tr = document.createElement("TR");
    tr.setAttribute("id", "myTR");

    fetch(url)
        .then(function (response)
=>
    {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            return response.json();

        } else {
            throw `error with status ${response.status}`;
        }
    }
)
.
    then(data => data);


.
    then


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
    .then((data) => {
    let {token,...otherinfo} = data; // if token is not nested and given directly
    localstorage.setItem('token',token); // if you want to store in local storage
    return token;
    })
 })
```

but not sure how your response is coming from your server can you show response when you hit that api